TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')
I am getting the following error during run time: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')
Can any one help me?
export const LoginForm = () => {

    
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>("");
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState<string | undefined>("");
    const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

const form =useForm<z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>>({

    resolver: zodResolver(LoginSchema),
    defaultValues: {
        email:"",
        password:"",

    },

});

const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
    
    setError("");
    setSuccess("");
    
    startTransition(() => {

        login(values)
        .then((data) => {
           ** setError(data.error);
            setSuccess(data.success);
**
        });
        
    });

I was able to successfully log in, but an error appears at the bottom of the screen as shown below in the image.

login function:
"use server";

import * as z from "zod";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import { signIn } from "@/auth";
import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas";
import { DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT } from "@/routes";

export const login = async(values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
    
const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(values);

    if (!validatedFields.success) {
        return { error: " Invaid fields!"};
    }

const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;

try {

    await signIn("credentials", {
        email,
        password,
        redirectTo: DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT
    })

} catch (error) {
    if(error instanceof AuthError) {
        
        switch(error.type) {
        case "CredentialsSignin":
            return { error: "Invalid credentials!"}

        default:
            return { error: "Something went wrong!"}           
            
        }
    
    }

    throw error;

}

};

Outcome after successful login followed by page error as shown in image:
{
  "user": {
    "name": "kalyan Thatavarti",
    "email": "kalyan.thatavarti@gmail.com",
    "image": null
  },
  "expires": "2024-11-29T18:49:11.316Z"
}


You are trying to call .then() on a function. 
.then() can only be called on a promise:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then
Make sure then your login function returns a promise.
(It now returns nothing if the try succeeds.)
